# Git branch not working for me in Xcode

Tags: xcode, git

I am working off a github branch, call it "main12"

I then do a `git checkout -b newFeature.`

I do some work on newFeature

I then need to go back to main12 to do some work

I close down Xcode.
I switch to main12 via terminal `git checkout main12`
Open xcode and verify xcode is on the main12 branch.

All my changes made in newFeature are now in my main12 branch

What gives? Did I miss a step?  Why wouldn't my code in main12 be the way I left it?

Comment: Have you commit the code before switching to main12?

Answer (score 0):

Did you commit or stash the changes made to newFeature? If not, probably the command `git checkout main12` have failed. Closely watch the command line output of that command and verify.

Any changes you make to the current branch should be committed or stashed(discard temporarily, store it back whenever you need) before checking out another branch.

Try the following command before you checkout main12

`git commit -am "some commit message here"`

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the case that you forgot to commit your code before `checkout` to `main12` branch. Currently, you should have uncommitted code (marked in Xcode as M/A besides the file name). You can switch back to `newFeature` branch, commit the code, and switch back to `main12` branch.